# Why the neural network doesn't seem to learn? (built from scratch)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, octave

I'm currently going through Andrew Ng's Machine Learning Course on Coursera. I have implemented a neural network from scratch using the knowledge i gained from that. But the network doesn't seem to learn no matter what i do.

Dataset details : I have used the MNIST database of handwritten images. (0 - 9 numbers). It has 5000 training data. I have took the first 4999 as training data.

The network consists of three layers. Input layer (400 nodes), hidden layer (26 nodes), output layer (10 nodes).

Program in Octave :

**Main.m**

```
load('ex4data1.mat');


X = X(1:end-1, :);
y = y(1:end-1, :);

size(X) % Dimension = 4999x400
size(y) % Dimension = 4999x10

noOfFeatures = size(X,2) + 1;

%Theta1 = randInitializeWeights(25,noOfFeatures); % Dimension = 25x401
%Theta2 = randInitializeWeights(26,10); % Dimension = 26x10


Theta = [Theta1(:); Theta2(:)];

learning_rate = 0.01;

for iter = 1:200,
 [J, grad] =nnCostGrad(Theta, X, y);
  Theta = Theta - (learning_rate * grad);
  plot(iter,J);
  hold on;
endfor

predict(Theta, [0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   8.5606e-06  1.9404e-06  -0.00073744 -0.008134   -0.01861    -0.018741   -0.018757   -0.019096   -0.016404   -0.0037819  0.00033035  1.2766e-05  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00011642  0.00012005  -0.014044   -0.028454   0.080383    0.26654 0.27385 0.27873 0.27429 0.22468 0.027756    -0.0070632  0.00023472  0   0   0   0   0   0   1.2834e-17  -0.00032629 -0.013865   0.081565    0.3828  0.85785 1.0011  0.96971 0.93093 1.0038  0.96416 0.44926 -0.0056041  -0.0037832  0   0   0   0   5.1062e-06  0.00043641  -0.0039551  -0.026854   0.10076 0.64203 1.0314  0.85097 0.54312 0.3426  0.26892 0.66837 1.0126  0.9038  0.10448 -0.016642   0   0   0   0   2.5988e-05  -0.0031061  0.0075246   0.17754 0.79289 0.96563 0.46317 0.069172    -0.003641   -0.041218   -0.05019    0.1561  0.90176 1.0475  0.15106 -0.021604   0   0   0   5.8701e-05  -0.00064093 -0.032331   0.2782  0.93672 1.0432  0.598   -0.0035941  -0.021675   -0.0048102  6.1657e-05  -0.012377   0.15548 0.91487 0.9204  0.10917 -0.017106   0   0   0.00015625  -0.00042772 -0.025147   0.13053 0.78166 1.0284  0.75714 0.28467 0.0048687   -0.0031869  0   0.00083649  -0.037075   0.45264 1.0318  0.53903 -0.0024374  -0.0048029  0   0   -0.00070364 -0.012726   0.16171 0.77987 1.0368  0.80449 0.16059 -0.013817   0.0021488   -0.00021262 0.00020425  -0.0068591  0.00043171  0.72068 0.84814 0.15138 -0.02284    0.00019897  0   0   -0.0094041  0.037452    0.69439 1.0284  1.0165  0.88049 0.39212 -0.017412   -0.0001201  5.5522e-05  -0.0022391  -0.027607   0.36865 0.93641 0.45901 -0.04247    0.0011736   1.8893e-05  0   0   -0.019351   0.13    0.97982 0.94186 0.77515 0.87363 0.21278 -0.017235   0   0.0010994   -0.026179   0.12287 0.83081 0.7265  0.052444    -0.0061897  0   0   0   0   -0.0093656  0.036835    0.69908 1.0029  0.6057  0.3273  -0.03221    -0.048305   -0.043407   -0.057515   0.095567    0.72651 0.69537 0.14711 -0.012005   -0.0003028  0   0   0   0   -0.00067657 -0.0065142  0.11734 0.42195 0.99321 0.88201 0.74576 0.72387 0.72334 0.72002 0.84532 0.83186 0.068883    -0.027777   0.00035914  7.1487e-05  0   0   0   0   0.00015319  0.00031735  -0.022917   -0.004144   0.38704 0.50458 0.77489 0.99004 1.0077  1.0085  0.73791 0.21546 -0.026962   0.0013251   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00023637  -0.0022603  -0.025199   -0.037389   0.066212    0.29113 0.32306 0.30626 0.087607    -0.025058   0.00023744  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6.2094e-18  0.00067262  -0.011315   -0.035464   -0.038821   -0.037108   -0.013352   0.00099096  4.8918e-05  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0])
```

**nnCostGrad.m**

```
function [J, grad] = nnCostGrad (Theta, X, Y)

  X = [ones(size(X,1),1) X]; % Dimension = 4999x401

  m = size(X,1);

  Theta1 = reshape(Theta(1:10025), 25,401); % Dimension = 25x401
  Theta2 = reshape(Theta(10026:end), 10, 26); % Dimension = 26x10


  % Forward Propagation

  a_1 = X;
  z_2 = a_1 * Theta1'; % Dimension = 4999x25
  a_2 = [ones(size(X,1),1) sigmoid(z_2)]; % Dimension = 4999x26

  z_3 = a_2 * Theta2'; % Dimension = 4999x10
  a_3 = sigmoid(z_3);

  modified_y = zeros(size(Y,1), 10);
  for i=1:size(Y,1),
    modified_y(i,Y(i)) = 1;
  endfor

  regularize_term = (1/(2*m)) *  ( sum(sum(Theta1(:,2:end).^2,2),1) + sum(sum(Theta2(:,2:end).^2,2),1) );
  J = (1/m) * sum(sum(- ( modified_y .* log(a_3) + (1-modified_y) .* log(1-a_3) ),2),1) + regularize_term;



  % Back Propagation

    delta1 = 0;
    delta2 = 0;

    d3 = a_3 - modified_y; % Dimension = 4999x10
    d2 = (d3 * Theta2)(:, 2:end) .* sigmoidGradient(z_2); % Dimension = (4999x10 * 26x10')(:, 2:end) .* 4999x25 => 4999x25 .* 4999x25 = 4999x25

    delta1 = delta1 + (d2' * a_1); % Dimension = delta1 + (4999x25' * 4999x401) = 25x401 
    delta2 = delta2 + (d3' * a_2); % Dimension = delta2 + (4999x10' * 4999x26) = 10x26
        size(delta2)

    Theta1_grad = (1/m) * delta1; % Dimension = 25x401
    Theta2_grad = (1/m) * delta2; % Dimension = 10x26
        size(Theta2_grad)

    regularized_Theta1 = ((1/m) * Theta1);
    regularized_Theta2 = ((1/m) * Theta2);
            size(regularized_Theta2)

    Theta1_grad(:,2:end) = Theta1_grad(:,2:end) + regularized_Theta1(:,2:end);
    Theta2_grad(:,2:end) = Theta2_grad(:,2:end) + regularized_Theta2(:,2:end);

grad = [Theta1_grad(:); Theta2_grad(:)] ;    

endfunction
```

**predict.m**

```
function a_3 = predict (Theta, X)
  X = [ones(size(X,1),1) X];
  Theta1 = reshape(Theta(1:10025), 25,401); % Dimension = 25x401
  Theta2 = reshape(Theta(10026:end), 10, 26); % Dimension = 26x10

  a_1 = X;
  z_2 = a_1 * Theta1'; % Dimension = 4999x25
  a_2 = [ones(size(X,1),1) sigmoid(z_2)]; % Dimension = 4999x26

  z_3 = a_2 * Theta2'; % Dimension = 4999x10
  sigmoid(z_3)
  [number, index] = max(sigmoid(z_3), [],2);
  a_3 = index;
endfunction
```

**sigmoid.m**

```
function val = sigmoid (z)
  val = 1 ./ (1+exp(-z));
endfunction
```

**sigmoidGradient.m**

```
function val = sigmoidGradient (z)
  val = sigmoid(z) .* (1-sigmoid(z));
endfunction
```

*After 100 iterations, the cost is 3.2709, the prediction is 10 where it should be 1,
the prediction set is,*

```
 [ 0.097546   0.100517   0.100398   0.100093   0.100162   0.100293   0.099932   0.100491   0.100063   0.100789 ]
```

I can't figure out where i'm going wrong. Please help. Thanks a lot in advance!

View the complete code here - https://github.com/virtualdesigner/Digit_recognizer

Comment: I goodly while since I did that exercise, but lets see if I can help a bit.

Comment: A few random thoughts - haven't gone through the code thoroughly


(1) Why have you commented out the random initialisation tie-breakers. That would be one reason precisely for learning to get stuck.


(2) Not sure about your predict.m function. Looks like you aren't applying sigmoid() to the hidden layer bias weights. You also have a spurious run of sigmoid() on z3 that you don't do anything with. 


(3) You have some hard-coded array sizes - never good and perhaps hide bugs. Sometimes good to use size() but where functionsd are closely linked perhaps pass as params for consistency.

Comment: You also seem to be adding bias inputs to X repeatedly after passing X to a new function such as nn- why not add them once at loading and let them pass through when you pass X as a parameter. Easier to follow code => easier to debug (aside from reducing run time)

Also when combined with picking up dimensions using size() you run the risk of adding the bias inputs repeatedly. By using parameters passed with the function you would be more likley to catch this with a run-time error. 

Not sure if any of this will help - no smoking gun!

Comment: There is no hyperparameter to control the strength of regularisation (but really you can set that to 0 until it is working anyway)

Comment: In `main.m` your Theta is undefined and takes the value of whatever it was in your workspace beforehand. Without the randomization that you've commented out, there is the danger that it will introduce a high degree of redundancy, or trap you into a local minimum.

Comment: @DukeBouvier Sorry, i mistakenly commented out the theta values while pasting the code here. But still the network doesn't seem to learn..

Comment: I have added the link to view the complete code in the question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why test on only one digit? You need have a larger test set to know how good your classifier is. All you can say now is whether it works on the one digit or not. This might be the odd one out digit that you can never get right.

Comment: Oh. I'll add more testing data. But, that one testing data is from the training data, moreover it is from the first row of the 4999 training rows.

Comment: I have this time tested 100 testing data which is from the training data. But the prediction accuracy is 0%

Comment: Surely your should get c. 10% by chance; perhaps this is a clue.

Comment: Oh yeah. There is something either in my code or calculation.. But as far as i have spend my time on it, can't figure out the issue.

Comment: The network seems to learn dataset with less features. I think there is another approach for large features rather gradient descent. Thank you for your suggestions guys.